# What expression works with setLayoutProperty in mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I am able to toggle the opacity of individual groups within a tileset. Unfortunately this does not hide the data when clicked on. As the layers are stacked this is a problem.

```
const toggleGroups = (layerName) => {
 if (mapRef.current && !loading) {
   let map = mapRef.current.getMap()
   let expression = ['match', ['get', `${layerName}_class`]]
  
   Object.keys(mapboxGroups[layerName]).forEach(key => {
     expression.push(parseInt(key), mapboxGroups[layerName][key] ? 0.58 : 0)
   })

   expression.push(0)
   map.setPaintProperty(layerName, 'fill-opacity', expression)
 }
}
```

The setLayoutProperty visibility works for other layers without groups and it also hides the layer data from being shown when layers are stacked.

I have tried to convert my function to work with setLayoutProperty but I get an error.

```
  const toggleGroups = (layerName) => {
if (mapRef.current && !loading) {
  let map = mapRef.current.getMap()
  let expression = ['match', ['get', `${layerName}_class`]]
  
  Object.keys(mapboxGroups[layerName]).forEach(key => {
    expression.push(parseInt(key), mapboxGroups[layerName][key] ? 'visible' : 'none')
  })

  map.setLayoutProperty(layerName, 'visibility', expression)
}
```

}

Error message reads : layers.risk.layout.visibility: expected one of [visible, none]

Is there another way of hiding the groups within a layer and also hiding their properties so when stacked the data is not visible when clicked?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for a solution to this.

```
  const toggleGroups = (layerName) => {
   if (mapRef.current && !loading) {
    let array = []
    let map = mapRef.current.getMap()
    let group = mapboxGroups[layerName]
    let filter = ['match', ['get', `${layerName}_class`], array, true, false]

    Object.keys(group).forEach(key => {
      if (group[key]) array.push(parseInt(key))
    })
  
    if (!Object.values(group).some(val => val)) {
     filter = ['match', ['get', `${layerName}_class`], [1,2,3,4], false, true]
    }

    map.setFilter(layerName, filter)
  }
}
```